# How to identify the variable that determines the number of thumbnails shown in Wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress, firebug

I've been through all my WP theme files and can't find the line of code in any of them that determines that there should be 10 thumbnails/posts shown on my homepage [http://www.themanwhohaseverything.co.uk](http://www.themanwhohaseverything.co.uk/)

I want to change it to 18 or 24.

Is it possible to identify the variable using Firebug or similar?

Thanks very much.

Ben

Comment: I think it's the Wordpress default, so there may not be a variable at all. You need to edit the theme files, locate where the posts are queried and add the number of posts there (or introduce a custom query)

Comment: Thanks Pekka - that might explain it.

I think the relevant piece of code is this bit. Is this where I need to put a custom query do you think? (my php isn't so good)

 'global $blog_ID;'

  '$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?' 'get_query_var('paged') : 1;'

  'query_posts('cat=-' . $blog_ID. '&paged='.$paged);'

  'while (have_posts()) : the_post();$i++;?>' 

      
'*thumbnail code*'


  '<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>'

Comment: sorry - I think i might be able to change it from the Dashboard>Settings>Reading inside the drupal administration. I think that's the obvious answer I've overlooked for the last few hours! Thanks for helping though Pekka. Sorry for my ineptitude!

Answer (score 0):

The setting that determines how many posts to show on your home page is under settings - > reading.  This can be overridden in a custom query using the `posts_per_page` argument.

[image]